# Спарсить строки из массива Java

Tags: java

У меня есть массив SomeArray, куда я кладу строки, затем мне нужно спарсить их в другой массив, как я это могу сделать?

```
static void parsing(List<String> SomeArray, int n){
        ArrayList<String> SomeMasos = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < SomeArray.size(); i++){
            String N = SomeArray.get(i);
            SomeMasos.add(String.valueOf(N.split(" ")));
        }
    }
```

Такой способ вообще не работает.

Comment: Извините, я живу в России, и мне непонятно слово "спарсить". Что это?

Comment: Преобразовать в массив с элементами типа int

Comment: N.split(" ") разбивает строку на массив с разделителем пробел. Вам нужно сначала объявить массив строк, и разбить строки. И затем работать с этим массивом. А массив вы не объявили

Comment: А как можно объявить массив, чтобы он подстраивался под количество строк?

Comment: К тому же у меня есть массив строк, которые надо разбить, я не понимаю, как разбить каждую строку в этом массиве и создать из этих слов другой массив

Comment: В интернете всё есть. String string = "004 0345 56";
String[] parts = string.split(" "); В итоге у вас массив из трех элементов

Comment: Это получается, будьте пожалуйста внимательнее, У МЕНЯ ЕСТЬ МАССИВ СТРОК, которые нужно преобразовать в массив слов из этих строк

Comment: Это вы уже внимательнее, составьте блок схему, если так не получается

Comment: Так что должно получиться в итоге: слова или элементы типа `int`?  И в каком виде: массива 'String[]/int[]' или списка `List<String>/List<Integer>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если требуется получить из массива строк все целые числа, то алгоритм следующий:

- Разбиваем исходный массив строк на подстроки (то есть каждая строка исходного массива будет иметь свой массив строк)
- Проходим циклом по каждой подстроке и пробуем извлечь из каждого слова целочисленное значение (кстати, работает с каким угодно стандартным типом, нужно лишь поменять ***Integer*** на любой тип (*Double, Boolean*, и т.д.)

Можно использовать простые циклы, можно использовать лямбды. Я предпочитаю второе. Код с готовым решением:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static ArrayList<Integer> parse(List<String> stringList) {
        // итоговый список чисел
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();

        stringList.stream()
                // преобразовываем каждую строку исходного массива
                // в массив строк
                .map(string -> string.split(" "))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                // после чего обрабатываем каждое слово каждой подстроки
                // для получения целого числа
                .forEach(word -> {
            try {
                // получаем целое число
                Integer num = Integer.valueOf(word);
                // добавляем его в наш итоговый список
                integerList.add(num);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // т.к. метод valueOf() может выбросить исключение,
                // мы все проводим в блоке try catch, чтобы
                // метод не "завис"
                System.out.println(word + " is not a number!");
            }
        });
        return integerList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("354 654 3");
        list.add("af3 34 23");
        list.add("654");
        list.add("65gf54");
        list.add("23");
        list.add("93412");

        System.out.println(parse(list));
    }
}
```

Результат работы:

```
af3 is not a number!
65gf54 is not a number!
[354, 654, 3, 34, 23, 654, 23, 93412]
```

Если же лямбды слишком сложны, есть аналогичный вариант с циклами:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> parse(List<String> stringList) {
        // итоговый список чисел
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String string : stringList) {
            String[] s = string.split(" ");
            for (String word : s) {
                try {
                    Integer num = Integer.valueOf(word);
                    integerList.add(num);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println(word + " is not a number!");
                }
            }
        }
        return integerList;
    }
```